# To generate a distance function?

Tags: python, polynomial-math

Given the value of X and Y
where X is load and Y is run-time

```
X =[0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15]

Y =[139, 130, 141, 142, 145, 146, 146, 147, 147, 149, 150, 152, 152, 152, 154, 155, 165, 169, 175, 211, 224]
```

I tried using their difference but didn't work

```
D = abs(X[0]-Y[0])
```

I need a distance function to be generated based on the values of X and Y.If any one can suggest be some ways of doing it.

Comment: "need a distance function" ... for what purpose? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to group and form clusters of closely related values

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Eucleidian distance as it is defined for n-dimensions:

```
D=sqrt(Sum(xi-yi)*2)
```

for your case would be:

```
Dxy=sqrt((0.1-139)*2+....+(0.15-224)*2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import math     
sum = 0
for i in range(0, len(X)):
    sum += pow(abs(X[i] - Y[i]), 2)
D = sqrt(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in  module  ,that is more **pythonic**:

```
map(operator.sub, X,Y)
```

Demo:

```
>>> X =[0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15]
>>> 
>>> Y =[139, 130, 141, 142, 145, 146, 146, 147, 147, 149, 150, 152, 152, 152, 154, 155, 165, 169, 175, 211, 224]
>>> new_list=map(operator.sub, X,Y)
>>> new_list
[-138.9, -129.85, -140.85, -141.85, -144.85, -145.85, -145.85, -146.85, -146.85, -148.85, -149.85, -151.85, -151.85, -151.85, -153.85, -154.85, -164.85, -168.85, -174.85, -210.85, -223.85]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using numpy?

```
import numpy 
X = asarray(X)
Y = asarray(Y)
dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((X-Y)**2))
```

The np.sqrt call ist not necessary but saves the import of the math library.